# Youtube - Check When Video Is Loaded

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I am using AJAX to dynamically change the video ID of my Youtube video. My AJAX call is nearly instant, but I've noticed that there is a delay when firing my request at Youtube to get the content for the my next video. As a result, I want to hide my Youtube player as I am waiting for a response from Youtube.

My question is how do I detect when my Youtube video has finished loading via JavaScript?

`<iframe id="ytplayer" class="hide" type="text/html" width="840" height="470" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>`

EDIT - How my AJAX works:

When a user clicks on the video button on my website, a modal will appear. My AJAX pulls a video id from my database as the modal is loading, and modify `#ytplayer`'s src attribute to include this video id. The modal is then rendered onto the page, but I am still waiting for a response from Youtube.

Comment: finished loading as in, all the content can be completely played if its offline?

Comment: @JohnRiselvato Affirmative.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are loading it, but AJAX does have a native callback:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'myYouTubeData.html',
  success: function(){
    alert('success');
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('failure');
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I will modify my question to include how my AJAX performs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), you can perhaps use `player.getPlayerState():Number` or you can use the Events API in that same page. Perhaps use `onStateChange` and listen for the `YT.PlayerState.ENDED` to hide the player with CSS. When it switches to some other state like `YT.PlayerState.PLAYING` or `YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING` then you can show it again.

Answer (score 0):

What i am doing is to blend a background with the video when the video it is loaded to make the transition smoother.

```
    // set up iframe player, use global scope so YT api can talk
    window.player;
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
        player = new YT.Player('tubular-player', {
            width: options.width,
            height: Math.ceil(options.width / options.ratio),
            videoId: options.videoId,
            playerVars: {
                controls: 0,
                showinfo: 0,
                modestbranding: 1,
                wmode: 'transparent'
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    window.onPlayerReady = function (e) {
        resize();
        if (options.mute)
            e.target.mute();
        e.target.seekTo(options.start);
        e.target.playVideo();
    }

    window.onPlayerStateChange = function (state) {
        if (state.data === 0 && options.repeat) { // video ended and repeat option is set true
            player.seekTo(options.start); // restart
        }
        if (state.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) { // video ended and repeat option is set true
            $(".initial-video-image").fadeTo(1000, 0);
        }
    }
```